# Can Raman spectrometers detect Rayleigh scattering?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, scattering, spectroscopy, raman-spectroscopy

Can Raman spectrometets detect Rayleigh scattering?
The sample I have got turned blue after annealing.
And I am wondering if this happened because of Rayleigh scattering. I saw some articles about Rayleigh scattering and it seems like Raman can detect it at 0 cm$^{-1}$ area.

If detecting is possible, how should I change the settings in the Raman spectrometer to do so?

Comment: Spectroscopy is spectroscopy.

Comment: oh i shouldve said spectrometer! sorry english isn't my first language i made a mistake

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.